# Positioning div on top of text, without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a base site right now that has a grey background with text on top, moving/animated with external javascript. I want another div to be positioned on top of this background div, but I don't want to sacrifice page centering by using absolute positioning. Any ideas?

```
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <p id="backgroundText">
        </p>

        <div id="mainBody">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
}

head {
    display: none;
}

body {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#background {
    z-index: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

p#backgroundText {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #494949;
    font-size: 13px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

div#mainBody {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use relative positioning.

```
div#mainBody {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
}
```

In order to utilize z-index properties you must use a position property of some kind.